# Zip for Windows Server 2008 command line?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-command-prompt, compression

I know that this has been asked before, but I have not found an answer for Windows Server 2008. Most references I found are with the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit, but not for 2008.

I know that there are 3rd party tools, but since there is a solution for 2003, I would assume that there is something for 2008?

Comment: Have you simply tried the 2003 resource kit tool under 2008?  Many of the tools still work.

Comment: Second that. MS even officially states that the W2k3 resource kit tools work on W2K8.   But which solution for command-line ZIP do you mean ? As far as I know there is no ZIP/UNZIP utility in the resourcekit.  I would just install 7zip on the server and call it a day.

Comment: No, I have not tried that. I figured there should be a Resource tool kit for 2008 or so, but will give it a try.

Comment: I was finding something similar and I found this post
very useful,
http://superuser.com/a/112094/78710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install 7 Zip

http://www.7-zip.org/

Put it in your path if needed.

If you really want the tool from Windows, install the 2k3 Resource kit and use the "compress" utility

Resource Kit:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657

Compress Utility

```
C:\>compress /?

Syntax:

COMPRESS [-R] [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] Source Destination
COMPRESS -R [-D] [-S] [ -Z | -ZX ] Source [Destination]

Description:
Compresses one or more files.

Parameter List:
-R Rename compressed files.

-D Update compressed files only if out of date.

-S Suppress copyright information.

-ZX LZX compression. This is default compression.

-Z MS-ZIP compression.

Source Source file specification. Wildcards may be
used.

Destination Destination file | path specification.
Destination may be a directory. If Source is
multiple files and -r is not specified,
Destination must be a directory.
```